# Tag merge or synonym request: [simple-machines-forum] and [smf-forum]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

The tags [simple-machines-forum](/questions/tagged/simple-machines-forum) and [smf-forum](/questions/tagged/smf-forum) should be merged and/or one should be a synonym of the other.  The latter has a tag-wiki and the former doesn't.

Comment: Not sure if tags can be renamed, but: smf-forum (simple machines forum forum) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome